# Raspberry Pi USB mount error (sd* letter always changes)

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, mount, torrent

I wanted to set up a torrent server with my Raspberry Pi 2 and with a 16 GB USB.

My fstab:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
/dev/sda1       /mnt/usb        ext4    defaults          0       0
```

It worked for a few minutes, and then the transmission-daemon had input-output error. Then I saw in the /proc/partitions file, that the USB isn't   sda any more, but sdb. So I mounted it manually to /mnt/usb (sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb). But after a few minutes transmission-daemon had the same error, and sdb changed to sdc. I also tried to format my USB, but it didn't work even if I had an NTFS filesystem on my USB.

Dmesg said some errors too:

```
[  450.036334] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 42 using dwc_otg
[  450.907015] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 42
[  450.916493] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb]
[  450.916523] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[  450.916541] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB:
[  450.916553] cdb[0]=0x2a: 2a 00 01 78 80 70 00 00 f0 00
[  450.916618] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 24674416
[  450.916650] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 770637824 size 1114112 starting block 3084332)
[  450.916672] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084046
[  450.916719] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084047
[  450.916739] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084048
[  450.916757] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084049
[  450.916776] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084050
[  450.916793] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084051
[  450.916811] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084052
[  450.916828] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084053
[  450.916846] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084054
[  450.916863] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 3084055
[  450.917060] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 770637824 size 1114112 starting block 3084392)
[  450.917221] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 770637824 size 1114112 starting block 3084422)
[  450.917375] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 770637824 size 1114112 starting block 3084452)
[  450.917530] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 770637824 size 1114112 starting block 3084482)
[  450.917682] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 770637824 size 1114112 starting block 3084512)
[  450.917835] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 770637824 size 1114112 starting block 3084542)
[  450.917985] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 770637824 size 1114112 starting block 3084544)
[  450.918065] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb]
[  450.918080] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[  450.918096] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB:
[  450.918106] cdb[0]=0x2a: 2a 00 01 78 81 60 00 00 f0 00
[  450.918168] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 24674656
[  450.918193] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 770637824 size 1114112 starting block 3084362)
[  450.918327] Aborting journal on device sdb1-8.
[  450.918404] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdb1-8.
[  450.926386] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[  450.965297] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[  450.965364] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  451.005340] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.005551] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.005911] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.006405] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.006540] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.007847] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): __ext4_read_dirblock:884: error -5 reading directory block (ino 2, block 0)
[  451.022015] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm gvfsd-trash: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.022288] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm gvfsd-trash: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.039755] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.039933] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.040011] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  451.636367] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 43 using dwc_otg
[  451.741850] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[  451.741876] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  451.741894] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Flash Disk
[  451.741911] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: General
[  451.741927] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 0107000000011210
[  451.743734] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  451.744258] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
[  453.040465] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     General  USB Flash Disk   1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  453.041762] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  453.042685] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 31490048 512-byte logical blocks: (16.1 GB/15.0 GiB)
[  453.043669] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  453.043698] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  453.044665] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  453.126409] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 43 using dwc_otg
[  453.554715]  sdc: sdc1
[  453.565480] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  461.356064] EXT4-fs (sdc1): recovery complete
[  462.443547] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  462.536762] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 43 using dwc_otg
[  463.558275] EXT4-fs error: 5 callbacks suppressed
[  463.558315] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  463.560901] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  463.563529] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  463.565388] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  463.634130] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  463.636388] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  578.048876] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 43 using dwc_otg
[  580.069629] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 43
[  580.088851] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]
[  580.088881] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[  580.088900] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB:
[  580.088912] cdb[0]=0x2a: 2a 00 00 c4 26 10 00 00 08 00
[  580.088977] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 12854800
[  580.089000] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1606594, lost sync page write
[  580.089107] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982174)
[  580.089129] buffer_io_error: 232 callbacks suppressed
[  580.089144] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981888
[  580.089192] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981889
[  580.089215] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981890
[  580.089236] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981891
[  580.089260] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981892
[  580.089280] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981893
[  580.089301] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981894
[  580.089322] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981895
[  580.089343] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981896
[  580.089364] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 2981897
[  580.089510] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982204)
[  580.089693] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982234)
[  580.089878] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982264)
[  580.090063] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982294)
[  580.090245] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982324)
[  580.090428] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982354)
[  580.090616] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982384)
[  580.090791] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982414)
[  580.091004] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 260640 (offset 352321536 size 1441792 starting block 2982444)
[  580.091497] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdc1-8.
[  580.091733] Aborting journal on device sdc1-8.
[  580.091790] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdc1-8.
[  580.165173] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[  580.165223] EXT4-fs (sdc1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  580.169410] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.169620] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.169719] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.169794] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.169973] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.170050] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.170112] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.170179] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.178082] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.178334] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[  580.678933] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 44 using dwc_otg
[  580.784418] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[  580.784448] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  580.784466] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Flash Disk
[  580.784482] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: General
[  580.784499] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 0107000000011210
[  580.786308] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  580.786843] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
[  582.083966] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     General  USB Flash Disk   1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  582.085891] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  582.087744] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 31490048 512-byte logical blocks: (16.1 GB/15.0 GiB)
[  582.088711] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[  582.088740] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  582.089890] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  582.097623]  sdd: sdd1
[  582.102909] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  583.864490] EXT4-fs (sdd1): recovery complete
[  583.864537] EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  583.949085] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 44 using dwc_otg
[  905.411955] EXT4-fs error: 5 callbacks suppressed
[  905.411994] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  905.415351] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  905.418646] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  905.421045] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  905.422771] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[  905.425328] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1619.454353] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1671.150949] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 44
[ 1671.152308] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 1671.159210] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1671.159556] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd]
[ 1671.159575] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[ 1674.198477] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 45 using dwc_otg
[ 1674.303962] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[ 1674.303988] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1674.304006] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Flash Disk
[ 1674.304023] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: General
[ 1674.304040] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 0107000000011210
[ 1674.305851] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1674.306351] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[ 1675.608760] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     General  USB Flash Disk   1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1675.610728] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 1675.611007] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 31490048 512-byte logical blocks: (16.1 GB/15.0 GiB)
[ 1675.612004] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 1675.612032] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 1675.612989] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1675.621378]  sdd: sdd1
[ 1675.626508] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1677.426106] EXT4-fs (sdd1): recovery complete
[ 1677.426151] EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 1677.508594] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 45 using dwc_otg
[ 1699.728493] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 45 using dwc_otg
[ 1706.888517] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 45 using dwc_otg
[ 1707.218479] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1708.088519] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 45 using dwc_otg
[ 1708.988506] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 45 using dwc_otg
[ 1710.979144] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 45
[ 1710.988746] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd]
[ 1710.988775] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[ 1710.988794] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB:
[ 1710.988807] cdb[0]=0x2a: 2a 00 00 c4 26 40 00 00 18 00
[ 1710.988871] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 12854848
[ 1710.988973] Aborting journal on device sdd1-8.
[ 1710.989059] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdd1-8.
[ 1710.991653] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1710.991959] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd]
[ 1710.991984] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[ 1711.033811] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm gvfsd-trash: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1711.034142] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #2: comm gvfsd-trash: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1711.588496] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 46 using dwc_otg
[ 1711.693976] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[ 1711.694007] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1711.694025] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Flash Disk
[ 1711.694041] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: General
[ 1711.694058] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 0107000000011210
[ 1711.695898] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1711.696514] scsi host9: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[ 1712.738232] ieee80211 phy6: rt2x00lib_rxdone_read_signal: Warning - Frame received with unrecognized signal, mode=0x0000, signal=0x0008, type=2
[ 1712.738810] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected
[ 1712.738810]
[ 1712.748414] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected
[ 1712.748414]
[ 1712.748456] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected
[ 1712.748456]
[ 1712.748493] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected
[ 1712.748493]
[ 1712.748549] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected
[ 1712.748549]
[ 1712.748664] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected
[ 1712.748664]
[ 1712.788536] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 39
[ 1712.788563] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 40
[ 1712.788851] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: unregister 'smsc95xx' usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
[ 1712.788919] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[ 1712.834183] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1712.849322] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 46
[ 1712.851093] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 41
[ 1712.857125] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1712.863743] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1712.868764] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1712.871981] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1712.881372] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1712.889661] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260609: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1712.890923] wlan0: deauthenticating from 64:66:b3:14:6f:de by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1712.899551] EXT4-fs error (device sdd1): ext4_find_entry:1289: inode #260639: comm transmission-da: reading directory lblock 0
```

I also have problems occasionally with my USB WLAN adapter. Is it hardware issue with my USB or the Raspberry Pi, or is it just a software problem?

Comment: Do you use a powered USB hub? It may be powering issue.

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be getting powerspikes. If you're using a 0.7 A adapter you should change to a 1 A instead. Because, while the Raspberry Pi can survive on 0.7 A, it will have a hard time sustaining your USB adapters.

Comment: You are probably right, because a month ago I changed the power adapter, and before the change it was much better. And the new adapter has 0.55A... So I have to buy a 1A USB adapter. Thank you for the answer!